# Каким членом предложения является сравнительный оборот "чем я" в предложении ПАПА СИЛЬНЕЕ, ЧЕМ Я

Tags: синтаксис

Каким членом предложения является сравнительный оборот, присоединяемый союзом ЧЕМ в предложении: ПАПА СИЛЬНЕЕ, ЧЕМ Я.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

***Папа сильнее, чем я.***

Итак, надо сделать синтаксический разбор.  Вероятно, такие предложения разбирают в школе.

Попробуем сравнить: ***Папа сильнее  (кого?) меня.***  Дополнение?  Или всё сочетание  (*сильнее меня*) является сказуемым? Тоже вариант. Надо поискать в книгах или в Интернете похожие примеры, но вот что-то найти не получается.

**Тогда почитаем Грамматику-80**  (сокращенный вариант).
http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5312&0a0=1714#223

КАТЕГОРИЯ СТЕПЕНИ СРАВНЕНИЯ

§ 223. Форма сравнительной степени, или компаратив, обозначает, что названный ею качественный признак проявляется в большей степени, чем тот же признак, названный формой положительной степени: веселый – веселее, сильный – сильнее, тихий – тише, сладкий – слаще, твердый – тверже.

Средствами выражения морфологических значений степеней сравнения служат для положительной степени – вся совокупность форм полных прилагательных, а для сравнительной степени – **ОСОБЫЕ НЕИЗМЕНЯЕМЫЕ ФОРМЫ КОМПАРАТИВА, которые употребляются в сочетании с РОД. П.** ИМЕНИ (розы красивее гвоздик; дыни слаще арбузов) **или в объединении С СОЮЗОМ ЧЕМ** (розы красивее, чем гвоздики; дыни слаще, чем арбузы).

1. Напишем такой ответ: ***Папа сильнее меня. Папа сильнее, чем я.***

Сказуемое: ***сильнее меня, сильнее, чем я.*** Компаратив  входит в состав сказуемого вместе с зависимыми словами. Но по поводу обособленного оборота есть, конечно, сомнения.

Интересно, какую оценку можно за это получить в школе? (Да и здесь тоже.) Но надеюсь, что педагоги поправят.

**2. Другой вариант**: сильнее (кого?) меня – **дополнение**, а обособленный оборот занимает **позицию дополнения**. В то же время  **сравнение с чем-либо** здесь является **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫМ элементом**, а не распространителем.

**Из грамматики:** "Возможны употребления компаратива **и без зависимого слова**: 1) когда признак одного предмета сравнивается с тем же признаком другого предмета (или других предметов), известного **из контекста или ситуации**: В том краю леса темнее, Зимы дольше и лютей (Твардовский); 2) когда признак предмета сравнивается с тем же его признаком по отношению **к предшествующему или последующему состоянию**.

**3. Третий вариант** – это вообще не приравнивать оборот к  каким-либо  второстепенным членам (наверное, самый разумный). Обособленными обычно считают определения и обстоятельства, которые легко могут менять свой статус: они практически при сходной структуре предложения могут без особого труда обособляться или не обособляться. Здесь же мы имеем более **сложную конструкцию, к таким трансформациям не приспособленную.**

Из современной грамматики:

Различаются конструкции (1) собственно сравнительные и (2) **несобственно  сравнительные**, причем ко второму типу относят **градационное сравнение (союз ЧЕМ)** и приравнивание (союз КАК И).  При градационном сравнении связь между предметами **сочинительная**, а осуществляется  она с помощью **подчинительного союза** ЧЕМ через компаратив,  то есть это **двусторонняя** связь.

И вот оборот с такой сложной структурой просто не имеет смысла считать обособленным  второстепенным членом, таким как обособленные обстоятельства и определения. Пусть он лучше остается **просто сравнительным оборотом**.

**4. Но как  подчеркивать оборот с союзом ЧЕМ?**  Папа сильнее, чем я. У брата лучше оценки, чем у меня. Такое впечатление, что лучше обозначить **параллельную сочинительную связь**: папа – я, у брата – у меня, то есть подчеркивать как второе подлежащее в первом случае и как дополнение во втором случае.

**Но это должно как-то обозначаться в  методиках,** если уж спрашивается у школьников. А если и не спрашивается, то надо быть готовым к подобным вопросам со стороны любознательных учеников.